# How to create a new column from a list of words in each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe column which has so many words. I would like to create another column that will extract from each row, every word in any row that is in the list of words I supplied.

This is the list of words I supplied

```
skills = ['Qaulitative research', 'wireframing', 'figma', 'frame x', miro, 'mockflow', 'User Persona',  coding, 'empathy', 'sketch',
'communication', 'problem solving']

def skill_list(data):
  for item in data:
    if item in data:
      return item

all_files['skills'] = all_files.apply( lambda x: skill_list(x['job_description'].split()),axis=1)
```

Here is my table (dataframe)
[The current dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaWQv.png)

I want is to be like this
[Expected dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doriK.png)

Comment: Please update your post with raw data (not images) so your example is reproducible.

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, data or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

[Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a regex pattern with your skill words then use `str.findall` to extract skills:

```
pattern = fr"({'|'.join(skills)})"
df['Skills'] = df['Description'].str.findall(pattern).str.join(', ')
```

Output:

| Name | Description | Skills |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | User Persona Qauntitative research Qaulitative research wireframing | User Persona, Qaulitative research, wireframing |

Comment: Thank you so. This is good. Solves the problem